# Column name of maximum of each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe and i wanted a column filled with maximum value of each row so i used this :

```
 df_1['Highest_Rew_patch'] = df_1.max(axis=1)
```

output:

```
    Patch_0  Patch_1  Patch_2  ...  Patch_7  exp_patch  Highest_Rew_patch
0      0.0     70.0     70.0  ...      0.0          3               70.0
1      0.0     74.0     74.0  ...      0.0          4               74.0
2      0.0     78.0     78.0  ...      0.0          4               78.0
3      0.0     82.0     82.0  ...      0.0          4               82.0
4      0.0     82.0     82.0  ...      0.0          5               82.0
5      0.0     86.0     86.0  ...      0.0          6               86.0
6      0.0     90.0     90.0  ...      0.0          6               90.0
7      0.0     94.0     94.0  ...      0.0          6               94.0
8      0.0     98.0     98.0  ...      0.0          6               98.0
9      0.0     98.0     98.0  ...      0.0          7               98.0
```

However i want a little different result:

```
Patch_0  Patch_1  Patch_2   Patch_7  exp_patch  Highest_Rew_patch
0        0.0      70.0      70.0       3            Patch_2,Patch_7...
1        0.0      74.0      74.0       4            Patch_2,Patch_7...
```

So instead of the highest value of the row , i want the header of that column for that particular row which has highest value(s).

Comment: Add a small sample data from `df_1`

Comment: i dont understand? more rows from the output?

Comment: No, the original data. Do `df_1.head(10)`, and add the terminal output to the question.

Comment: alright, i edited the question as u asked for.

Comment: the title is a bit misleading: what you really want is the names of _all_ the columns that contain the max. Otherwise, the answer would simply be `df_1.idxmax(axis=1)`, which gives you a single column name per row, even if other columns also share that maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the columns starting by `Patch` and then just keep the column names where the value is equal to the max:

```
>> s = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Patch')].apply(
   lambda s: s.index[s.eq(s.max())].tolist(), axis=1)

>> s 

0    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
1    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
2    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
3    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
4    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
5    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
6    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
7    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
8    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
9    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
```

Or joining as string:

```
>> s = s.apply(lambda s: ','.join(s))

>> s
0    Patch_1,Patch_2
1    Patch_1,Patch_2
2    Patch_1,Patch_2
3    Patch_1,Patch_2
4    Patch_1,Patch_2
5    Patch_1,Patch_2
6    Patch_1,Patch_2
7    Patch_1,Patch_2
8    Patch_1,Patch_2
9    Patch_1,Patch_2
dtype: object
```

Then just assign the new column:

```
df['Highest_Rew_patch'] = s
```

**Update**

To select other order than the max, we can use [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), take advantage that it remove duplicates and then select the last element:

```
>> n_order = 2
>> s = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Patch')].apply(
      lambda s: s.index[s.eq(s.nlargest(n_order)[-1])].tolist(), axis=1)

>> s
0    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
1    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
2    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
3    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
4    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
5    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
6    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
7    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
8    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
9    [Patch_1, Patch_2]
dtype: object
```

Comment: is it possible to find the second highest, third highest Patches as well using the similar approach?  I am not sure if max function alternatives can be used to find second or third highest. Can you guide ? @Mabel Villalba

Comment: @Kshtj I just updated the solution to include any order, not just the max. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df['Highest_Rew_patch']=df.filter(like='Patch').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.eq(x.max())].index), axis=1)
```

`apply` on `axis=1`, then join all the indices of `x` on `,`  which is equal to the maximum value.

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   Patch_0  Patch_1  ...  exp_patch                   Highest_Rew_patch
0      0.0     70.0  ...          3  Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_4, Patch_6
1      0.0     74.0  ...          4           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6
2      0.0     78.0  ...          4           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6
3      0.0     82.0  ...          4           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6
4      0.0     82.0  ...          5           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6
```

Comment: changes the whole df and the highest rewarding patch column doesnt give expected results.

Comment: 0      Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_4, Patch_6, Highest_Re...
1           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6, Highest_Rew_patch
2           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6, Highest_Rew_patch
3           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6, Highest_Rew_patch
4           Patch_1, Patch_2, Patch_6, Highest_Rew_patch

Comment: Because the question doesn't include all the columns, can you please try `df.head(10).to_dict()` and add it to the question?

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_head'

Comment: `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: {'Patch_0': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Patch_1': {0: 70.0, 1: 74.0, 2: 78.0, 3: 82.0, 4: 82.0},
 'Patch_2': {0: 70.0, 1: 74.0, 2: 78.0, 3: 82.0, 4: 82.0},
 'Patch_3': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Patch_4': {0: 70.0, 1: 63.0, 2: 57.0, 3: 51.0, 4: 51.0},
 'Patch_5': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Patch_6': {0: 70.0, 1: 74.0, 2: 78.0, 3: 82.0, 4: 82.0},
 'Patch_7': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'exp_patch': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Highest_Rew_patch': {0: 70.0, 1: 74.0, 2: 78.0, 3: 82.0, 4: 82.0}}

Comment: @Kshtj, check now.

Comment: under the Highest_Rew_patch column all values are NaN.